# Set class from <select> if selected option contains ID='answer' in HTML/JavaScript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am completely new to HTML and JQuery, and I can't figure out how I can set a class for my select element if the currently selected option has an ID="answer". I want to do this to check if the multiple choice question is correct.

If this is impossible to do this in JQuery, JavaScript would also be fine. I just want to prevent making a DataBase query and thought that JQuery would be the best route to take.

This is the current html section that I have:

```
<form id="ansForm" class="testClass1">
    <div id="QuestionForm" name="QuestionForm">
    <label>Question 1: This is a question </label>
    <select class="form-control select-class">
        <option value="1" class="ans-class" id="answer">Answer1</option>
        <option value="2" class="ans-class">Answer2</option>
        <option value="3" class="ans-class">Answer3</option>
        <option value="4" class="ans-class">Answer4</option>
    </select>
    <label>Question 2: This is another question </label>
    <select class="form-control select-class">
        <option value="1" class="ans-class">Another Answer</option>
        <option value="2" class="ans-class">Just some text</option>
        <option value="3" class="ans-class" id="answer">Test</option>
        <option value="4" class="ans-class">Test2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
    onclick="checkAnswers()">Check</button>
</form>
```

When I click the button it runs a Javascript function called: "checkAnswers()".
This function should check if the option that is selected in the dropdown box, has an id="answer". In this case, that would be if option one is selected. And if that option is selected, I want the background color of the select element to change.

How would I go about checking the currently selected dropdown options' ID? And how do I do this for more than 1 question at a time?
And how would I add a class programaticly in JavaScript to that select element so it can change BG color?

This is what I tried in JavaScript:

```
var s = document.getElementsByClassName("select-class");
var idSelectedOption = s[s.selectedIndex].id;
alert(idSelectedOption);
```

But that returns an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
I think that is because it returns an array from all classes. How would I go about checking every single one of them? And changing the background colors of the ones that have the correct option selected?

Thanks in advance,
Mats.

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same id. Use a custom `data` attribute or a class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data-*` attributes instead of `id` as you should not have multiple elements having same `id` value in a document.

> `getElementsByClassName` will return `nodelist` hence you need to iterate through elements and then apply conditions accordingly. `Array.prototype.forEach.call` is used in example below to iterate through elements.

Try this:

```js
function checkAnswers() {
  var s = document.getElementsByClassName("select-class");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(s, function(elem) {
    var idSelectedOption = elem[elem.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id');
    if (idSelectedOption == 'answer') {
      var selectedAnswer = elem[elem.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value');
      alert(selectedAnswer);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="ansForm" class="testClass1">
  <div id="QuestionForm" name="QuestionForm">
    <label>Question 1: This is a question</label>
    <select class="form-control select-class">
      <option value="1" class="ans-class" data-id="answer">Answer1</option>
      <option value="2" class="ans-class">Answer2</option>
      <option value="3" class="ans-class">Answer3</option>
      <option value="4" class="ans-class">Answer4</option>
    </select>
    <label>Question 2: This is another question</label>
    <select class="form-control select-class">
      <option value="1" class="ans-class">Another Answer</option>
      <option value="2" class="ans-class">Just some text</option>
      <option value="3" class="ans-class" data-id="answer">Test</option>
      <option value="4" class="ans-class">Test2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkAnswers()">Check</button>
</form>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ct00md9d/1/)

Comment: Thanks allot! This is excatly what I wanted, even a little bit too much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two elements with the same id. Use a custom data attribute or a class instead

After fixing that, this code should to the trick. I tried to use vanilla JavaScript since you didn't indicate using jQuery.

```js
// Lazy: Bind the event to the form.
document.getElementById('ansForm').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  
  var selectElement = event.target;
  
  // Only respond if the clicked element is one of the selects.
  if (selectElement.classList.contains('select-class')) {
    
    // Get the option that is currently selected.
    var selectedOption = selectElement[selectElement.selectedIndex];
    // Check if this option contains the class 'answer'.
    var isAnswerSelected = selectedOption.classList.contains('answer');
    
    console.log(isAnswerSelected);
    
    // Remove the indicators. You could easily use classList.toggle, but the second
    // argument is not supported in IE.
    
    // selectElement.classList.toggle('right', isAnswerSelected);
    // selectElement.classList.toggle('wrong', !isAnswerSelected);

    // So, second best. Just remove both and re-add the class we want.
    selectElement.classList.remove('right');
    selectElement.classList.remove('wrong');
    selectElement.classList.add(isAnswerSelected?'right':'wrong');
    
  } else {
    // Ignore clicks on any other element.  
  }
});
```

```css
.right {
  color: green;
}

.wrong {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<form id="ansForm" class="testClass1">
    <div id="QuestionForm" name="QuestionForm">
    <label>Question 1: This is a question </label>
    <select class="form-control select-class">
        <option value="1" class="ans-class answer">Answer1</option>
        <option value="2" class="ans-class">Answer2</option>
        <option value="3" class="ans-class">Answer3</option>
        <option value="4" class="ans-class">Answer4</option>
    </select>
    <label>Question 2: This is another question </label>
    <select class="form-control select-class">
        <option value="1" class="ans-class">Another Answer</option>
        <option value="2" class="ans-class">Just some text</option>
        <option value="3" class="ans-class answer">Test</option>
        <option value="4" class="ans-class">Test2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
    onclick="checkAnswers()">Check</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for jQuery approach,

```
$(function(){
    // This will bind 'click' event handler to element with id 'checkBtn'
    $('#checkBtn').on('click', function(){

        // This gets all selects element which has class containing 'select-class'.
        var $selects = $('select.select-class');

        // Iterate all the selects element.
        $selects.each(function(k, v){
            // Get the option for this current select element which has an id of 'answer'.
            var $selectAnswerOpt = $(this).children('option#answer');

            // Get the value attribute of the option element.
            var answer = $selectAnswerOpt.attr('value');

            // Get the selected value for the select element.
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();

            // Checking if the selected value for the select element is the option that has an id of 'answer'
            if (selectedValue == answer)
            {
                // If the selected value has the id of 'answer'
                $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
            }
            else
            {
                // Else
                $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf934rfw)

Comment: This is an awesome solution! Thank you, I already used Rayon's approach, but still props to you for such a good, and nicely commented answer.